# dependent current source polarity

Tags: current-source, circuit-theory

In this question, I apply the current cycle law,
I find the current i1 to 25uA. I find the voltage on the dependent current source -2 volts. When I go through the formulas, there is no problem here.
but the voltage on the dependent current source is negative (-) obviously confused. I assume that the arrow of the current source is positive and the starting part is negative.
so is this dependent current source supplying current in the opposite direction of the picture because -2 volts are formed on the current source?

[image]

Comment: If your numbers are right then that is what it is. The current source will produce whatever voltage is necessary for the circuit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The marked polarity for \$v\$ on the current source is the **assumed** polarity. When setting up a circuit for analysis we may not know the actual polarity of the voltage, so we just make an assumption that lets us write the equations.

If we solve the equations and the **value** of the assumed voltage is negative it just means that the polarity of the actual voltage is the opposite of the polarity of the assumed voltage. There is nothing wrong with this, voltages can have a positive or negative value.

Comment: thank You so much

Answer (score 1):

[image]

key point : The direction of the voltage of the current sources may change according to the circuit they are in.
A current source aims to provide a constant current by changing the voltage across it.
https://slideplayer.com/slide/9412471/
Published by Dorothy Powers